# Hold down key to constantly move tank

Tags: python, pygame

I'm currently trying to make the tanks move(whhich they already do) but I want to make it so that you can just hold down WASD or the 4 arrow keys to have it contantly moving. Right now, you have to click the arrow key over and over again for it to move.

```
import pygame, assetloader
from pygame.locals import *
import random, time, math
import pygame

GRAD = math.pi/180
blue = (0, 0, 255)

wallRects = []



maze = [[] for i in range(25)] 





assetloader.set_asset_path("assets/")




class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, pos):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image, self.rect = assetloader.load_image("Tank.png", -1)
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        self.rect.clamp_ip(screen.get_rect())
        self.dir = 0
        self.vel_y = 0
        self.vel_x = 0
        self.rows = pos[0]
        self.cols = pos[1]
        self.x = self.cols * gsize
        self.y = self.rows * gsize
        self.orig_image, self.orig_rect = assetloader.load_image("Tank.png", -1) 
        self.orig_rect.x = self.x
        self.orig_rect.y = self.y
        self.orig_gun_pos = self.orig_rect.midtop
        self.ammo = 5
        self.vel = [0, 0]
        self.dead = False






    def draw(self, screen):
        image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, self.dir)
        screen.blit(image, self.rect)





    def update(self):
        oldCenter = self.rect.center

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = oldCenter
        screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()


        if keys[K_UP]:



            if (0 < self.dir and self.dir < 90) or (-360 < self.dir and self.dir < -270):
               self.vel_x = -1

               self.vel_y = -1
            elif (270 < self.dir and self.dir < 360) or (-90 < self.dir and self.dir < 0):
                self.vel_x = 1
                self.vel_y = -1
            if (90 < self.dir and self.dir < 180) or (-270 < self.dir and self.dir < -180):
                self.vel_x = -1
                self.vel_y = 1

            elif (180 < self.dir and self.dir < 270) or (-180 < self.dir and self.dir < -90):
                self.vel_x = 1
                self.vel_y = 1

            if self.dir == 0 :
                self.vel_x = 0
                self.vel_y = -1
            if self.dir == 90 :
                self.vel_x = -1
                self.vel_y = 0
            if self.dir == 180:
                self.vel_x = 0
                self.vel_y = 1
            if self.dir == 270:
                self.vel_x = 1
                self.vel_y = 0





            self.rect.move_ip(self.vel_x, self.vel_y)

        elif keys[K_DOWN]:

            if (0 < self.dir and self.dir < 90) or (-360 < self.dir and self.dir < -270):
               self.vel_x = 1

               self.vel_y = 1
            elif (270 < self.dir and self.dir < 360) or (-90 < self.dir and self.dir < 0):
                self.vel_x = -1
                self.vel_y = 1
            if (90 < self.dir and self.dir < 180) or (-270 < self.dir and self.dir < -180):
                self.vel_x = 1
                self.vel_y = -1

            elif (180 < self.dir and self.dir < 270) or (-180 < self.dir and self.dir < -90):
                self.vel_x = -1
                self.vel_y = -1

            if self.dir == 0 :
                self.vel_x = 0
                self.vel_y = 1
            if self.dir == 90 :
                self.vel_x = 1
                self.vel_y = 0
            if self.dir == 180:
                self.vel_x = 0
                self.vel_y = -1
            if self.dir == 270:
                self.vel_x = -1
                self.vel_y = 0 

            self.rect.move_ip(self.vel_x, self.vel_y)


        if keys[K_LEFT]:
            self.dir += 5
            if self.dir > 360:
                self.dir = 0
        elif keys[K_RIGHT]:
            self.dir -= 5
            if self.dir < -360:
                self.dir = 0






        if not screen_rect.contains(self.rect):
            self.rect.clamp_ip(screen_rect)



class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image, self.rect = assetloader.load_image("New Piskel.png", -1)
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        self.dir = 0
        self.rect.clamp_ip(screen.get_rect())


    def draw(self, screen):

        image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, self.dir)
        screen.blit(image, self.rect)

    def update(self):
        screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[K_w]:

            if (0 < self.dir and self.dir < 90) or (-360 < self.dir and self.dir < -270):
               self.vel_x = -1

               self.vel_y = -1
            elif (270 < self.dir and self.dir < 360) or (-90 < self.dir and self.dir < 0):
                self.vel_x = 1
                self.vel_y = -1
            if (90 < self.dir and self.dir < 180) or (-270 < self.dir and self.dir < -180):
                self.vel_x = -1
                self.vel_y = 1

            elif (180 < self.dir and self.dir < 270) or (-180 < self.dir and self.dir < -90):
                self.vel_x = 1
                self.vel_y = 1

            if self.dir == 0 :
                self.vel_x = 0
                self.vel_y = -1
            if self.dir == 90 :
                self.vel_x = -1
                self.vel_y = 0
            if self.dir == 180:
                self.vel_x = 0
                self.vel_y = 1
            if self.dir == 270:
                self.vel_x = 1
                self.vel_y = 0




            self.rect.move_ip(self.vel_x, self.vel_y)

        elif keys[K_s]:

            if (0 < self.dir and self.dir < 90) or (-360 < self.dir and self.dir < -270):
               self.vel_x = 1

               self.vel_y = 1
            elif (270 < self.dir and self.dir < 360) or (-90 < self.dir and self.dir < 0):
                self.vel_x = -1
                self.vel_y = 1
            if (90 < self.dir and self.dir < 180) or (-270 < self.dir and self.dir < -180):
                self.vel_x = 1
                self.vel_y = -1

            elif (180 < self.dir and self.dir < 270) or (-180 < self.dir and self.dir < -90):
                self.vel_x = -1
                self.vel_y = -1

            if self.dir == 0 :
                self.vel_x = 0
                self.vel_y = 1
            if self.dir == 90 :
                self.vel_x = 1
                self.vel_y = 0
            if self.dir == 180:
                self.vel_x = 0
                self.vel_y = -1
            if self.dir == 270:
                self.vel_x = -1
                self.vel_y = 0 

            self.rect.move_ip(self.vel_x, self.vel_y)


        if keys[K_a]:
            self.dir += 5
            if self.dir > 360:
                self.dir = 0
        elif keys[K_d]:
            self.dir -= 5
            if self.dir < -360:
                self.dir = 0


        if not screen_rect.contains(self.rect):
            self.rect.clamp_ip(screen_rect) 


size = width, height = 500, 400
gsize = 25
start_x, start_y = 0, 0
bgColor = 255, 255, 255



pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)#, pygame.FULLSCREEN)
pygame.display.set_caption("Sample Sprite")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

p = Player(width/2, height/4, (3,4))
e = Enemy(width/2, height/4)


coll_font = pygame.font.Font(None, 30)



going = True
while going:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            going = False
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                going = False



        p.update()
        e.update()


        screen.fill(bgColor)

        p.draw(screen)
        e.draw(screen)






        pygame.display.flip()



pygame.quit()
```

There are no errors right now, but I want to have constant movement instead of re-pressing the keys over and over. Can someone explain to me how?

Comment: probably you have wrong indentions in `while going` loop and you run `update()` and other functions inside `for event` loop - so they are executed only when there is some event - like keypress. But key event is created only when key changes state from `not-pressed` to `pressed` (or from `pressed` to `not-pressed`), but not when you keep it preesed, so finally you have to press it again and again to create new event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem are wrong indentions in `while going`

Functions `update()` are inside `for event` loop so they are executed only when you move mouse, press/release mouse button or press/release key (when key change state from `not-pressed` to `pressed` or from `pressed` to `not-pressed`), but not when you keep key pressed.

```
going = True
while going:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            going = False
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                going = False

    # correct indentions - all outside of `for event` loop

    p.update()
    e.update()

    screen.fill(bgColor)

    p.draw(screen)
    e.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```